# Installing OpenWRT on a Netgear EX2700 WiFi Extender - .bin vs .img?

Tags: router, wireless-access-point, openwrt

I'm new, skimmed the pages, and am not sure if I'm heading in the right direction.  I've found the pages for [obtaining](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/obtain.firmware) [the right firmware](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/netgear/netgear_ex2700) and [how to flash](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/generic.flashing).

But I'm missing something. When I try to upload the openwrt firmware through the device's web UI, it only accepts `.img` files, but the firmware is a `.bin` file.

Do I need to do something?  Mix files?  Compile stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### About `.img` and `.bin`

In general `.img` usually indicates some sort of image of a device, like disk or flash memory content. It is a binary file.

The `.bin` extension refers to any binary file, I think.

Note that none of these extensions corresponds to a strict file format. I mean: you can recognize `.exe` or `.pdf` by analyzing the file content; there are formal structures you may expect, you can read some documentation etc.

In theory some files may fool you: they may appear to be `.exe` at the first glance, while not being one. On the other hand there are many files that are certainly not `.exe` – they lack magic number, specific structure and so.

The difference is: any binary (i.e. non-all-text) file may be formally described as `.bin`. You cannot say "this binary file is certainly not `.bin`". The same with `.img`. Moreover, every `.img` can be `.bin` – the scopes are so broad they carry almost no information on the file content.

#### File extensions in Linux world

Keep in mind OpenWRT is Linux based. Its developers think Linux. In Linux world file extensions hardly ever matter, they belong to DOS/Windows. Linux recognizes files by their content, no matter what the extension is. In fact what you (and Windows) call *extension* is just a part of filename in Linux.

I guess the developers chose the general `.bin` extension just to have one and not to confuse Windows and its users for whom a file without extension is always under suspicion.

Another speculation: Netgear people chose the general `.img` extension. As long as they publish their firmware with this extension only, it's a good thing that web UI is limited to `.img` because it helps to pick the right file (imagine flashing with `.mp3` by mistake).

#### Conclusion

**If you're sure you got the file that is right for your device** then change its extension to the one expected by web UI and proceed.

I'm a random guy on the Internet, you can trust me. :D